# Inject dynamic query string value from input to hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a webpage that have an input where the user can type a value (example: 10, 15, 30 etc...)

Then I have a link that should pass this value to my server, for example:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/myscript.php?inputValue=X">
```

Where X will be the value that the user type in the input...

How I can change the X, without rewrite all  tag or the link ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the following markup,

```
<input type='text' id='txt'/>
<a id='link' href="http://www.example.com/myscript.php"></a>
```

You can change the anchor like

```
var value = document.getElementById('txt').value;
var anchor = document.getElementById('link');
var href= anchor.href;
anchor.href= href.split('?inputValue=')[0].concat('?inputValue='+value);
```

*side note: it is not clear from the question when exactly you want the href to change*